# Identity Core - Relation between IdentityUser table and other tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

How to create a *one-to-many* relation between **IdentityUser** (auto generated Table) and other tables?

in my situation i have users table and want to add a one-to-many relation to Address table, and add **userId** and **userEmail** as rows to the **Address table**.

user table

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

addresses table

```
public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AddressName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstDetails { get; set; }
        public string SecondDetails { get; set; }
        public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string NearestLandmark { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Keep it as is and add UserId in the Address table. It will create a one-to-many between Users and Addresses.

Comment: now i already have UserId row in DB, I did what you suggested the problem was in DB 2 rows were created UserId and UserId1

Comment: I didn't see the UserId in the table Address. If you have it, then EF will automatically create the one-to-many relation.